# Assign a short name to a class attribute

Tags: python

I am using a Python package which read some type of data. From the data, it creates attributes to easily access meta-information related to the data.

How can create a short name to an attribute?

Basically let's assume the package name is `read_data` and it has an attribute named `data_header_infomation_x_location`

```
import read_data
my_data = read_data(file_path)
```

How can I instead create a short name to this attribute?

```
x = "data_header_infomation_x_location"
```

`my_data[1].x` gives an error **no attribute**

**Here is a full example from my case**

```
from obspy.io.segy.core import _read_segy

file_path = "some_file_in_my_pc)
sgy = _read_segy(file_path, unpack_trace_headers=True)

sgy[1].stats.segy.trace_header.x_coordinate_of_ensemble_position_of_this_trace
```

The last line gives a number. e.g., x location

what I want is to rename all this long nested attribute `stats.segy.trace_header.x_coordinate_of_ensemble_position_of_this_trace` with a short name.

trying for example

```
attribute = "stats.segy.trace_header.x_coordinate_of_ensemble_position_of_this_trace"

getattr(sgy[1], attribute )
```

does not work

Comment: I think that a lot of the vocabulary you use in your question doesn't match what you really mean. Please clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
from obspy.io.segy.core import _read_segy

attribute_tree_x = ['stats', 'segy', 'trace_header', 'x_coordinate_of_ensemble_position_of_this_trace']

def get_nested_attribute(obj, attribute_tree):
    for attr in attribute_tree:
        obj = getattr(obj, attr)
    return obj

file_path = "some_file_in_my_pc"
sgy = _read_segy(file_path, unpack_trace_headers=True)

sgy[1].stats.segy.trace_header.x_coordinate_of_ensemble_position_of_this_trace
x = get_nested_attribute(sgy[1], attribute_tree_x) # should be the same as the line above
```

You cannot request the attribute of the attribute in one go, but this loops through the layers to obtain the final value you are looking for.